# ManyToMany form field not render when loading form with Session data

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

I have a form with ManyToMany field .  When I load a form using data from DB it renders the M2M field perfectly.  However if I load a form using session data, that M2M field is not rendered (ie. no option is checked) correctly.

Scenario:  A user edits his existing record. While editing, he clicks on a button that takes a user to other URL.  The half filled form is saved in session.  When a user returns, he can continue editing his record other than retyping the changes made to date.  Also allow invalid form to be saved in session as it is not set save.

Session data was created using:

```
 request.session['form_inprogress'] = request.POST
```

Form is loaded with pre-filled data using session data and existing db record:

```
 currentrecord = Books.objects.get(id=123)
 booksform = BooksForm(request.session['form_inprogress'], instance=currentrecord)
```

For some reason the categories M2M field is not checked when rendered.  However M2M field renders perfectly if just displaying existing record:

```
booksform = BooksForm(instance=currentrecord)
```

Here is my HTML template:

```
<div class="form-group input_{{ form.categories.id_for_label }} multiplechoicefield">
    {{ form.categories.errors }}
    {{ form.categories.label }}
    {{ form.categories }}
</div>
```

I would greatly appreciate any pointers/advice.  Stuck on this issue for days and still don't know how to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of storing `request.POST` in your session, try storing the `cleaned_data` of a valid form. You'll see, when you have multiple choice fields, you can't access them via `request.POST` unless you use a special `getlist` method. You are probably just storing one of the values.
So my suggestion is: use a partial form to validate your partial data, and store the form's `cleaned_data`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use cleaned_data as the half filled form is not always a valid form.  Not heard of getlist method.  I will check this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is now working but not sure whether it is the most effective solution or not.  What I have done is store ManyToMany field (form.categories) value of form in progress in a separate session data.  I noticed that when debugging, request.session['form_inprogress'] showed a list value of form.categories after assigning request.POST to it.  But when checking request.session['form_inprogress'] in the next request/view, the session data had lost its list value.  I suspect that is because session keeps data as dict only.

So here is what I have done

1. Store the half completed form (valid/non-valid) into session.

   request.session['form_inprogress'] = request.POST

   request.session['cat_inprogress'] = request.POST.getlist('categories')
2. Form is loaded with pre-filled data using session data and existing db record:

   currentrecord = Books.objects.get(id=123)

   prefilled = request.session['product_inprogress']

   prefilled['categories'] = request.session.get('cat_inprogress')

   booksform = BooksForm(prefilled, instance=currentrecord)

Hope this would be of use/help to others.